# Can we tell something about rest mass from this plot of differential cross-section?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, mass, standard-model, leptons

What we can interpret from the plots below? My aim is to find any resonance peak for  di-leptons considering the  the produced gamma from quarks and antiquarks can annihilate to  lepton and anti lepton.

The  plot here is for 120 GeV CM energy proton proton scattering.

> [image]

EDIT:

I have changed the CM energy (14 TeV) and got a different cross-section peak for transverse momentum.

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transverse momentum was and is still a strong analysis variable for checking whether new phenomena appear in complicated hadronic interactions, as is proton proton scattering. The reason is that transverse momentum to the beam is invariant to lorentz boosts in the beam direction, so the distributions give a snapshot  of the maximum momenta possible in the interaction. High  $p_t$ are a signal for deep inelastic scattering, and also give an upper limit to a possible mass of a new resonance.

Choosing  high $p_t$ leptons in each event one enhances the probability of , for example the Z, to be in the sample and see the resonance enhanced in the invariant mass plot, and then one can use analysis to extract the true production crossection as in this publication [for example.](http://inspirehep.net/record/1359450?ln=en).

The first  plot you are showing *is not physical* as the the $p_t$ from a resonance will go from a maximum down to zero smoothly, because of the angular distribution of the  decay  momentum vectors of the produced resonance.

So from $p_t$ you can only get upper limits: supposing it is a resonance that has decayed completely perpendicularly then it would have a mass the invariant mass of the two supposed vectors as an upper limit.

edit after question edit.

The second plot is physically possible,  again one has to check with other variables in order to be able to extract a mass estimate , if it is not possible to get the invariant mass from the two leptons directly.

Comment: I have changed the CM energy, and I can see the change of the cross-section against  transverse momentum.  Could you please make a little comparison, that why the resonance will be physical in this case?

Comment: changing the CM energy of the created events will change the limits. You have to understand that the longitudinal variable is necessary to nail down a resonance, individualy you only get envelopes of behavior versus pt or angle or q^2, upper limits. we *are* talking of pt of the leptons in your plot, no?

Comment: yes we are talking about leptons.

Comment: The plot is perfectly physical if it accounts for detector effects. Many detectors have a threshold of $p_T$ before a particle can be detected.

Comment: @Chris  I want to remove the impression that it looks like a resonance, which is what I thought the question was aiming at. Yes it is possible if it is monte carlo that a lower limit exists for p_t, (although it looks high , 50GeV?) please note that the OP is generating the plot

Comment: @annav Fair enough. $50~\rm GeV$ is probably quite a bit higher a $p_T$ cut than you would see at a collider. Particular a $\sqrt s=120~\rm GeV$ one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really interpret anything from the transverse momentum of a lepton.

What you see here is simply zero events below a threshold, followed by an falling exponential, which is very standard for virtually all kinds of events at a collider.

In order to see a resonance, you want to plot the invariant mass of pairs of leptons, $m=\left(p_1+p_2\right)^2$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are four-momenta.

If longitudinal information is not available, you can also plot the "transverse mass," which is simply the invariant mass assuming $p_L$ is zero, and use statistical methods to determine the true invariant mass. This is often used for particles that decay as $\rm X\to Y+invisible$, since in a hadron collider the longitudinal momentum of invisible particles can usually not be detected.